# Visual C# combox1.Items.Add("test"); Error?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, .net-3.5

When I try to add an item to the combo box, I get:

"NullReferenceException was unhandled"
"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

This happens no matter how I do the code to add to the combobox.

```
comboBox1.Items.Add("test");
```

or

```
try
{
    Parties.Open();
    String test = "SELECT PartyName FROM Parties WHERE PartyID = 4";
    selectParty = new OleDbCommand(test, Parties);
    OleDbDataReader testing = selectParty.ExecuteReader();
    while (testing.Read())
    {
        MessageBox.Show(testing.GetValue(0).ToString());
        comboBox1.SelectedIndex =  comboBox1.Items.Add(testing.GetValue(0).ToString());
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    return;
}
```

(messy code above... frustration!)

I'm pretty new to .NET and C# and I don't understand what is going on here, everything everywhere I go is telling me that my code above should work, but it doesn't. MSDN simply lists:

```
comboBox1.Items.Add("Text");
```

Comment: where have you declared and created comboBox1?

Comment: When you debug through this, which object is `null`?  Where do you expect that object to be initialized?  Also, note that you're throwing away valuable information in your `catch` block.  You display the message, but you ignore the stack trace.  The stack trace will tell you what line of code threw the exception.  (You also ignore any potential inner exception, though I doubt there is one in this particular case.)

Comment: @Jason formName.Designer.cs

`private System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox comboBox1;`

Comment: @David when debugging, it's saying `comboBox1.Items.Add("Text");` is null. When I run it with the query, it's not catching it till the Exception is thrown.

Comment: @MadBurn: In your previous comment you show where `comboBox1` is declared, but not where it's initialized.  I would _think_ that Windows Forms would take care of that part for you, but if you've accidentally short-circuited that part of the Forms designer somehow then that could cause this.

Comment: @David THAT was my problem! You sir are amazing and I am an idiot. I wasn't thinking and was trying to do this before I initialized the form. It's been a long day. Answer my question and I'll select you!

Comment: @MadBurn: Go with @nmaait's answer instead of having me convert my comment to an answer.  He gave more specific information.  (Particularly the part about `InitializeComponent()`, which I wouldn't have guessed since I don't do a lot of WinForms.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where are you trying to add items to the ComboBox?

An exception will be thrown if you are calling the above code before InitializeComponent(); in the form constructor. Or if you are assigning the comboBox elsewhere in code.

Make sure all your code is done AFTER InitializeComponent(), this is the method that calls the code in the designer.

Answer (score 0):

visual studio will add an InitializeComponents() method when the designer is used to modify the UI.

You should have a call to the InitializeComponents() method in your form constructor body. If the code interacts with the controls, you need to put the code after the InitializeComponent call. Any code which doesn't interact with the controls is fine above or below InitializeComponents().

Also if you double click on a control in designer visual studio will create a Form_Load event handler which runs after the form constructor.

Comment: Sometimes even FormLoad() seems to be too early; I've had occasions where the Shown() event worked fine but Load() did not.